# Função dentro de um dicionário em Python

Tags: python, funções, random, dicionário

Estou tentando realizar um exercício onde ao criar um dicionário de arquivo log cuja chave seja retornada um número aleatório entre 100 e 9999 como matrícula da seguinte forma

```
 from datetime import date, time, datetime, timedelta  
    import random  
    def perguntar():  
     return input(' O que deseja realizar?\n' + 
                 '<I> Para inserir um usuário:  \n' +
                  '<P> Para pesquisar um usuário: \n' +
                  '<E> Para excluir um usuário: \n' +
                  '<L> Para listar um usuário: \n' +
                  '<S> Para sair: ').upper()
    
    def numero_de_matricula():
       num_matricula = random.randint(100, 9999)
    
    def inserir_dados(dicionario):
      dicionario[print('Matrícula: {}' .format(numero_de_matricula()))] = [input('Digite o login: ').upper(),
                        input('Digite o nome: ').upper(),
                         input('Digite a última data de acesso: '),
                         input('Digite a última estação acessada: ').upper()]

usuarios = {}
opcao= perguntar()
while opcao == 'I' or opcao =='P' or opcao =='E' or opcao == 'L':

  if opcao == 'I':
    
      inserir_dados(usuarios)
      print('Usuário cadastrado com sucesso: ')
```

Não é retornado nenhum erro, porém o valor da chave retornado é Matrícula: None.

Logo, gostaria de saber se:

> Estou declarando e chamando a função random corretamente para o que pretendo fazer?

Comment: Na função `numero_de_matricula` você não retornou o valor sorteado, apenas atribuiu na variável `num_matricula` que não é usada. Faça um `return num_matricula` nessa função, pois sem isso o retorno da função sempre será `None`, o que pode justificar aparecer esse valor como chave do dicionário.

Answer (score 1):

## Quanto a pergunta.

Não, você não está utilizando corretamente a função [`random.randint()`](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/library/random.html#random.randint) e as outras respostas apresentadas também não fazem um correto uso da função.

Como está cadastrando os alunos num dicionário fatalmente a função `randint()` irá sortear um número de matricula que já foi utilizado então haverá uma colisão de chave que implica na perda duma matricula já cadastrada.

Para resolver o problema não use `randint()`, o problema é mais complexo que caso de uso a qual foi projetada.
O que pode fazer é criar uma lista com a faixa de valores a serem usados como número de matricula e então embaralhar essa lista com a função [`random.shuffle()`](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/library/random.html#random.shuffle) e com uma [função geradora](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/howto/functional.html#generators) ir extraindo uma a um, quando solicitado um número de matricula com a função embutida [next()](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/library/functions.html#next):

Exemplo:

```
from random import shuffle

def matricula_gen():  
  matriculas = list(range(100, 1000))    #Cria uma lista com faixa válida de valores de matriculas.
  shuffle(matriculas)                    #Embaralha a lista.
  #Enquanto a lista matriculas não estiver vazia...
  while len(matriculas) > 0:
    yield matriculas.pop(0)              #...remove o primeiro elemento de matriculas e o retorna.

numero_de_matricula= matricula_gen()     #Cria o gerador de matriculas.
for _ in range(15):
  print(next(numero_de_matricula))       #Imprime 15 matriculas de teste.
```

## Inserindo no código da pergunta.

O código da pergunta apresenta muitos problemas:

- A função `perguntar()` pode ser simplificada.
- A função `numero_de_matricula()` não retorna valor e se retornasse gera chaves duplicadas.
- Na função `inserir_dados()` você está utilizando o resultado da função `print()` que é None como chave num dicionário.
- Seu menu de opções é exibido uma única vez.
- O laço de atividades não é adequado.

Então fiz algumas modificações para tornar o seu exemplo funcional e embutir a resposta a sua pergunta:

```
from datetime import date, time, datetime, timedelta  
from random import shuffle

menu = """O que deseja realizar?
<I> Para inserir um usuário:
<P> Para pesquisar um usuário:
<E> Para excluir um usuário:
<L> Para listar um usuário:
<S> Para sair: """

def matricula_gen():  
  matriculas = list(range(100, 1000))
  shuffle(matriculas)
  while len(matriculas) > 0:
    yield matriculas.pop(0)

proxima_matricula = matricula_gen()
    
def perguntar():  
  return input(menu).upper()
    
def numero_de_matricula():
  return next(proxima_matricula)

def inserir_dados(dicionario):
  try:
    dicionario[numero_de_matricula()] = [
      input('Digite o login: ').upper(),
      input('Digite o nome: ').upper(),
      input('Digite a última data de acesso: '),
      input('Digite a última estação acessada: ').upper()]
  except StopIteration:
    print("As matriculas estão esgotadas.")
    return False
  return True

usuarios = {}
while True:
  opcao = perguntar()
  if opcao == 'I':
    if inserir_dados(usuarios):
      print('Usuário cadastrado com sucesso. ')
    else:
      print('Usuário não pode ser cadastrado. ')
  elif opcao == 'P':
     pass
  elif opcao == 'E':
     pass
  elif opcao == 'L':
     pass
  else:
    print('Opção inválida.')
```

Comment: Outra opção é usar `random.sample`, aí daria para fazer algo como `for n in sample(range(100, 1000), 15): usar n` para gerar os 15 números sem repetição

Comment: @hkotsubo, Com certeza. E também é possível embaralhar direto um range com sample `sample(rng:= range(100, 1000), len(rng))`. Eu me foquei mais em rebater as resposta incentivando o uso do `randint()` o AP chegou a aceitar uma das respostas. Desculpa não poder fechar todas as possibilidades de solução.